# Javascript error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, xml

I have javascript code to find out the id of an element. It's working in Chrome, Safari, Opera and IE but when tested in Firefox using firebug the following error is displayed...

XML filter is applied to non-XML value({})

Does anyone know what this means and how I can get around this problem?

I appreciate any help.

Code found to be causing the problem...

```
testId = (event.target || event.srcElement).id;
```

Comment: How is it that you determined that code to be the source of the problem?  It could cause an error, but I seriously doubt it would cause *that* error.

Comment: Can you post the entire code in a JSFiddle? If not, how about just some more context here?  One line of code is a bit rough to go on.

Comment: not enough code to really understand the issue, if both are null or undefined you'll get an error like this though

Comment: -1 for incomplete question. If you improve the question, I will consider removing my downvote. The error is very likely to be caused by the occurrence of the `func.()` format in your actual code.